# How Parent object will create in Django Restframework nested serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How Parent object will create in Django Restframework nested serializers?
I want to show all children associated to the parent
but the problem is that when I try to create Parent it asks children list and as per the rule first parent will born

models

```
class Parent(models.Model)                                          
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
class Child(models.Model)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Serializers

```
class ChildSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('name')
class ParentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    children = ChildSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('name','children')
```

views.py

```
class ParentViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer
    queryset = Parent.objects.all()
```

Response:

```
{
    "children": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you add the code you are using to create parent

Comment: it is simple ModelViewSet

Comment: I'm getting this response :{
    "children": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}

Comment: it would be more helpful if you add code

Comment: @nishant I've made the changes in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your parentserializer with this

```
class ParentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
children = ChildSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = Parent
    fields = ('name','children')
```

update childSerializer with

```
class ChildSerializer(ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Child
    fields = ('name',)
```

Comment: have you added any child?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `required=False` to your nested `ChildSerializer`:

```
class ParentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    children = ChildSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('name','children')
```